# ReactJs nested function is not working

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs

Nested Function is not working in **ReactJs**. But its working in normal **Javascript**.

It shows this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getWlc' of undefined

How can I write nested function inside **ReactJs** function

```
function ldViewLayer() { 
    this.getWlc = function() { 
       alert('Try Alerts on Babel');
    } 
    this.getWlc();
}
ldViewLayer();
```

Comment: `this` is undefined in non-bound non-arrow functions in strict mode unless you invoke the function with `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correction:

```
function ldViewLayer { 
  const getWlc = () => { 
   alert('Try Alerts on Babel');
  } 
  getWlc();
}
ldViewLayer();
```

But what you was doing should be with classes, if you are using babel you are surely using es6.

In es6 syntaxe you should do:

```
class LdViewLayer {

  getWlc = () => {
    alert('Try Alerts on Babel');
  }
}

LdViewLayer ldViewLayer = new LdViewLayer();
ldViewLayer.getWlc();
```

Here is a very good code line : https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript